# SQL Server procedure - table every day - keep history once a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, history

I have procedure running in SQL Server. I want to run that procedure every day. Which will generate output table every day?

However, I want to keep history only once a month. I tried the following procedure but it keeps history every day.

How can I modify it a way that; this table should be created every day but I can keep history for only once a month e.g. on the last day of each month?

```
DECLARE @today AS DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

IF OBJECT_ID('[CI_Temp].[dbo].[Items_Scored_With_History]', 'U') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE [CI_Temp].[dbo].[Items_Scored_With_History]
    (
        id         INT          NOT NULL,
        sub        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        actual     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        preds      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        prob       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        pred_eval  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        score_date DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    )
ELSE

DELETE FROM [CI_Temp].[dbo].[Items_Scored_With_History]
WHERE score_date = @today;

INSERT INTO [CI_Temp].[dbo].[Items_Scored_With_History]
SELECT id,
   sub,
   actual,
   preds,
   prob,
   pred_eval,
   @today AS score_date,
FROM [CI_Temp].[dbo].[Items_Scored_With_History] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2012 or newer than version of SQL server.

you can ensure today's whether end of the month.

```
DECLARE @today AS DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

IF EOMONTH(@today, 0)=convert(date, GETDATE()) BEGIN 
  PRINT 'Today is end of months'
        --your script will be here. 
  END 
  ELSE
  PRINT 'Today is not end of the month'
```

Comment: `EOMONTH()` is available from SQL Server (starting with 2012).

Comment: @Başar Kaya sorry being naive. where I should add this condition in above procedure. could you please elaborate and help me embedding suggested condition so i have the working procedure. thanks advance

Comment: @JamesTaylor I edited my answer, it shows that where you can move to script.